# How to keep TabHost Omnipresent on 2.2 Froyo?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want the easiest way to keep a TabHost omnipresent no matter how deep into the activities I go. One idea I had was to use the Global Application object to keep the state and then layout the TabHost at the bottom of all activities. Is there a more standard way to do this? If not, what pitfalls might I run into with my idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this easily by using Fragments. Use a main Activity with a tabhost, have a container for each of the tabs. Then it's just a matter of replacing fragments.

Comment: I'm looking for a more Froyo friendly solution. Thanks though, good effort!

Comment: The [compatibility library](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html) provides this in a friendly way but if you're really wanted to use only original API Level 8 classes check TabActivity's super class [ActivityGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityGroup.html)